# How to execute/open whatever file in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

If I have a path of any kind of file (.doc , .pdf , .png ...etc) and I would like to open that file as it is opened via double click (no need to determine the host program). An example of what I mean is: `.doc` file needs to be opened via MS Word or whatever word processor exists in the machine and it is set as defualt word processor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "file.doc";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and pass the file name as an argument. This requires that the file extension be associated with the correct program.